# React-query get query service 1 step slow

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a react component fetching data like

`useGetMemeApi(orderBy, order)` is a `react-query` hook that looks like

```js
const {
  isLoading: getMemesLoading,
  data: getMemes,
  refetch: getMemesRefetch,
} = useQuery(
  "memes",
  () => {
    return queryService.getMemes(orderBy, order, templateId, tagId, page, limit);
  },
  { refetchOnMount: true },
);

const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = useState<MemeGetOrderByEnum>(MemeGetOrderByEnum.CreatedAt);
const [order, setOrder] = useState<MemeGetOrderEnum>(MemeGetOrderEnum.Desc);

const { getMemes, getMemesRefetch } = useGetMemeApi(orderBy, order);

console.log("memes", memes);
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(index, "index");
  if (getMemes) {
    setMemes(getMemes);
  }
  if (index === 0) {
    setOrderBy(MemeGetOrderByEnum.CreatedAt);
  }
  if (index === 1) {
    setOrderBy(MemeGetOrderByEnum.Likes);
  }
  if (index === 2) {
    setOrderBy(MemeGetOrderByEnum.Views);
  }
}, [getMemes]);
```

every time user clicks a tab it changes the index

when `index === 1` the `orderBy` does get changed however the network request is the previous `orderBy` value.
How do I fetch the latest orderBy by variable when I change the index?

Comment: So you basically want to refetch your query when `orderBy` changes? Also, I don't know why you are using a state to store the data, `react-query` is already handling this for you. It's a bit redundant.

Comment: yes refetch query with new orderBy variable change, I didnt notice thanks

Answer (score 0):

> How do I fetch the the latest orderBy variable when I change index?

This question has been asked a lot before, and it's also documented in the docs. The answer is: every dependency of the query needs to go to the query key, because react-query will automatically trigger a refetch if the key changes. so:

```
useQuery(
 ["memes", orderBy, order, templateId, tagId, page, limit],
 () => {
    return queryService.getMemes(orderBy, order, templateId, tagId, page, limit);
  },
);
```

relevant resources:

- https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/query-keys#if-your-query-function-depends-on-a-variable-include-it-in-your-query-key
- https://tkdodo.eu/blog/practical-react-query#treat-the-query-key-like-a-dependency-array
- https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-fa-qs#how-can-i-pass-parameters-to-refetch